# Can current window gets moved or resized?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domdocument

I am somehow familiar with javascript and I am trying to learn all the properties and methods of window, document etc objects.My question is related with methods like resizeBy,resizeTo,moveTo,moveBy.I am seeing all the methods in action and all they do is effecting new window opened based on examples online.Is it possible that this methods effect the default window opened in a tab without trying to do in other windows opened?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window:

> In a tabbed browser, each tab is represented by its own Window object; the global window seen by JavaScript code running within a given tab always represents the tab in which the code is running.

So, yes.